# using the command line and regex to determine words that start sentences

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have the text:

```
 This is a test. This is only a test! If there were an emergency, then Information would be provided for you.
```

I want to be able to determine which words start sentences. What I have now is:

```
 $ cat <FILE> | perl -pe 's/[\s.?!]/\n/g;'
```

This just gets rid of punctuation and replaces them with newlines, giving me:

```
 This 
 is 
 a 
 test 

 This
 is
 only
 a
 test

 If
 there
 were
 an
 emergency,
 then
 Information
 would
 be
 provided
 for
 you
```

From here I could somehow extract the words that have either nothing above them (start of file) or a blank space, but I am unsure of exactly how to do this.

Comment: See [Regex to match first word in sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767080/regex-to-match-first-word-in-sentence)

Comment: Not what I am looking for. When matching, it will include the punctuation. Also, I do not know how to extract the matches via grep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Perl of at least version 5.22.1 (or 5.22.0 and this case is not affected by [the bug described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36832662/1331451)), then you can use the sentence boundaries in your regular expression.

```
use feature 'say';

foreach my $sentence (m/\b{sb}(\w+)/g) {
    say $sentence;
}
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
perl -nE 'say for /\b{sb}(\w+)/g'
```

If called with your example text, the output is:

```
This
This
If
```

It uses `\b{sb}`, which is the sentence boundary. You can read [a tutorial at brian d foy's blog](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/06/perl-v5-22-adds-fancy-unicode-word-boundaries/) about it. The `\b{}` is called a unicode boundary and is described in [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5Cb%7B%7D%2C-%5Cb%2C-%5CB%7B%7D%2C-%5CB).

Comment: Hmm, nice solution. I thought about `\p{punct}` but of  course that gets comma (and other things) as well.

Comment: @Sobrique I just tried with different scripts, but that doesn't seem to work properly. At least on my command line, when I used the Armenian Google translation of the text, it broke.

Comment: What would the converse of this be i.e. capitalized words that don't start a sentence?

Comment: @basil `perl -nE 'say for /\B{sb}([A-Z]\w+)\b/g'` works. With your test, that's only _Information_.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/;

my @words = <DATA> =~ m/(?:^|[\.!]+)\s+(\w+)/g;

print Dumper \@words;

__DATA__
 This is a test. This is only a test! If there were an emergency, then Information would be provided for you.
```

So as a command line:

```
perl -ne 'print join "\n", m/(?:^|[\.!])\s+(\w+)/g;' somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gnu grep command to extract first after each period or `!` or `?`:

```
grep -oP '(?:^|[.?!])\s*\K[A-Z][a-z]+' file

This
This
If
```

Though I must caution you may get false results for cases like `Mr. Smith`.

**Regex Breakup:**

- `(?:^|[.?!])` - match start or DOT or `!` or `?`
- `\s*` - match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset to forget matched data
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - match a word startign with upper case letter

Comment: This is the simplest solution, but simbabque's solution works as well.

Comment: @basil And by _simple_ you mean _short_? :P

Comment: Yes.  I'm not a perl champion yet and I'm still getting used to just doing pattern matching from the command line. I don't mean to criticize or complain, I apologize.  Also, I tested this on a much larger document and it was, for some reason, catching on to single-characters that were not beginning of sentences. I changed the last * to a + to account for this. It works in my situation since I am working with a formal document that does not use first person pronouns but would be something to look into.

Comment: Yes indeed to avoid single character match use `[A-Z][a-z]+`